# automatically do print when viewing __doc__

Tags: ipython

Can I change the config file to automatically do a print when I'm viewing docstrings?

Contrast 6 and 7 on the iPython console below.

```
In [6]: zip.__doc__
Out[6]: 'zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]\n\nReturn a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element\nfrom each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated\nin length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.'

In [7]: print zip.__doc__
zip(seq1 [, seq2 [...]]) -> [(seq1[0], seq2[0] ...), (...)]

Return a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the i-th element
from each of the argument sequences.  The returned list is truncated
in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython already does that for you.  Use `?` instead of checking `__doc__`.

```
In [1]: zip?
```